# Как занести массив в базу данных mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

У меня есть вот такой массив который хранится в сессии `$_SESSION['product_ids']`.
Для занесения данных в БД я использую ORM RedBeanPHP.
Я написал вот такой код

```php
<?php
require 'db.php';
$orders = R::dispense('orders');
$orders->new_order = $_SESSION['logged_user'];
$orders->products = $_SESSION['product_ids']; //вот это массив
R::store($orders);
?>
```

Но у меня получается проблема, что массив не заносится и в БД и выдает ошибку

Comment: массив в json и хранить json-строку

Answer (score 1):

В mysql массивы не хранятся. Перед записью в БД используйте serialize или json_encode. После получения из БД unserialize или json_decode - вернет строку обратно в массив.